# How to show custom post template from single page?

Tags: custom-post-types

We know that in WordPress the default post template file is `single.php`. Now, I have one category name "members" and want *members* posts to show a custom template, like `content-members.php`.

I can do that via custom post template plugins. but is there a way to make that without plugins?

Maybe we can do that like this:

```
<?php
    if ( is_category( 'members' ) ) {

         get_template_part( 'content', 'members' );

    } else {

        get_template_part( 'content', 'common' );

    }
 ?>
```

I tried this already, but it's not working and I think category is not triggering here.

Comment: Where are you adding the above code?
Can you show me the whole code?

Comment: this is in single.php file...


<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div class="contentarea cf">

   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php
    if ( is_category( 'members' ) ) {

         get_template_part( 'content', 'members' );

    } else {

        get_template_part( 'content', 'common' );

    }
 ?>

   <?php endwhile;  ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you might need to use [in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) instead of [is_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category).

in_category() checks if the current post is in a category, is_category() checks if it's a category archive page.

Comment: wow... cool.. its work nicely :) thanks @Michelle .... now i am playing with it 

is that correct way now.. how i am doing for multipal categor post.. its work but just for am i in write way or not..

`<?php
    if ( in_category( 'salon' ) ) {

         get_template_part( 'content', 'salon' );

    } 
  if ( in_category( 'staff' ) ) {

         get_template_part( 'content', 'staff' );

    } 
 
 else {

        get_template_part( 'content', 'test' );

    }
 ?>
`

Comment: If this works perhaps you could mark it as correct? Your comment appears to be a brand new question regarding basic logic and PHP if else statements

Comment: @michelle Yes! Your response was way more elegant than mine. I'm not sure why I din't think of `in_category'.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the *single.php* template does not have any categories associated with it. You need to first get the category for that individual post.

**Single Category**

```
$category = get_the_category();
$cat_name = $category[0]->cat_name;
if ( $cat_name == 'Members' ) {

     get_template_part( 'content', 'members' );

} else {

    get_template_part( 'content', 'common' );

}
```

One thing to note here: This grabs only the first category associated with a post. If the post is in more than one category and "members" is not the first category in the list the post will not use the correct template.

**Multiple Categories**

If you want this to work with multiple categories you need to loop through them and look for the correct one.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$cat_exists = false;
foreach($categories as $category) {
    if( $category->name == 'Members' ) {
        $cat_exists = true;
        break;
    }
} 
if ( $cat_exists ) {

     get_template_part( 'content', 'members' );

} else {

    get_template_part( 'content', 'common' );

}
```

Comment: sorry guys... now i have one more request. now i want when member will open. i mean template come then show all members post. not only single post.. just all post. so for that i think  need to write something content-members.php file. i am not sure... can your guys tell me how can i do that. i tried some way but not work...

Comment: That would be best answered by submitting it as a new question. It's not really related to this question and it would be difficult to answer in the comments.

Comment: @epilektric... i already make seperate question

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110633/how-to-show-particular-category-all-post-in-custom-single-file/