# How to show particular category all post in custom single file

Tags: custom-post-types

Let me tell details about what I am trying to do,

I have one category call **Members** this category show in custom category file. and in category page show featured images with `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` so when I click thumbnail image it go to `single.php` file this is WordPress system for this **Members** category post I have one custom template also. which define in **single.php** bellow is code

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div class="contentarea cf">
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <h3>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </h3>
  <?php
    if ( in_category( 'members' ) ) {
         get_template_part( 'content', 'members' );
    } 

    else {
        get_template_part( 'content', 'common' );
    }
 ?>
  <?php endwhile;  ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

so when **Members** post open its go to content-members.php file and show post. but now I want in this page will show all **Members** post not only one post. I can't figure out yet how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) with the required arguments should list all the posts.
An Example:

```
$temp = $wp_query;
     <?php
        $type = 'post_type';
        $args = array (
        'post_type' => $type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1
         );
        $temp = $wp_query; // assign ordinal query to temp variable for later use
        $wp_query = null;
        $alt = false;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
          if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
  {
  the_title();
  }
  end while;
  endif;
 $wp_query = $temp; /* This is a must to make your template work properly
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: i not really undertand where i put this code and how to get title content feature image... etc

Comment: You put that code right after

<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div class="contentarea cf">

Also i have edited my answer to how to retrive the post tile with the_title() function.

Comment: @thanks sri.. but i think i can't tell properly or you don't understand clearly... actually the code you are seeing now that in single.php page.. this page have no problem... from this call members page (content-members.php) if that post from members category. we need something in members page. its blank now..

i need show this all members category post...

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake. Please use the code i gave you on content-members.php file.

Comment: its ok. @sri.. but show syntex error... would you check please again.

Comment: @pagol sorry, endif missing. Now please check the code. Also install debug bar and debug bar console plugins to find the exact error so that you can fix the errors.

Comment: thanks,,, but still same error... can you tell full coding

Comment: remember this is custome template file.. call from single.php file

Comment: @pagol I am afraid sorry. If you read my previous comment i suggested you to install debug plugins. They would give you the error and you can try and solve it. I cannot help you without knowing the problem you are facing. Also i have learnt that your question should help other people with a similar issue. So please be as clear as you can.

Comment: i got a solution and its work.. 

http://www.wphub.com/tutorials/list-posts-from-one-category/